# Screen turns black when running the game in fullscreen

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I play The Witcher 3 in fullscreen, it remains black. I can hear the audio and can go through the menus but I cannot see it.

I have two EVGA GTX 970 graphics cards with SLI is turned on. The reason I want to play in fullscreen is the performance, since I only get 45 fps when using borderless windowed mode.

Comment: I use 2 gtx 780 and get full 60 fps in windowed mode. On full settings. With hairworks. Did you download the new drivers? They are optimized for witcher 3.

Comment: Yes I have the latest driver, this setup is just 3 days old so everything is installed as clean as it can be. I had the same problem in my old setup but I used only a single 970 in the old one.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you play in one of the lower graphics quality modes?

Comment: Nope, I changed it in the GeForce Expirience to the lowest possible, launched the game, still black.

Comment: I found out that when I only connect 2 of my 3 screens it works